# Directional field of a nonlinear differential equation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

We are given the differential equation $\large\frac{\textrm dy}{\textrm dx}(x)=\frac{1}{3y(x)+x^2}+\frac{2}{4+x^2}$ and its directional field (see image below).

If this equation is solvable in closed form, I suspect it is not an easy solution and Wolfram Alpha confirms this idea by not giving such a solution.

We are asked:

- $\lim\limits_{x\to \infty}y(x)$ for the solution with $y(0)=-1$ and the solution with $y(0)=1$. For both of these I simply look at the directional field and follow the lines. So for $y(0)=-1$, I guess $\lim\limits_{x\to \infty}y(x)=-\infty$ and for $y(0)=1$, I guess $\lim\limits_{x\to \infty}y(x)=3$.
- for what initial conditions the solution $y(x)$ is bounded for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$. Once again I look at the directional field and guess that all solutions with initial conditions under or on the parabola that we see aren't bounded. So I say that all solutions with $y(0)>0$ are bounded.

The way I have "solved" these problems does not feel very nice and I am not sure it is right. I would like to hear if there are ways I could find the things I am asked using the differential equation, without relying as much on the directional field. I would also appreciate suggestions on how to find the solution which corresponds to the parabola (I'm not sure of course it's a parabola, but I think so) that we see.

[image: Directional field corresponding to given differential equation]

Comment: In regard to parabola, it has formula $y=\frac{-x^2}{3}$

Comment: @unknown Ok thanks, I think I see that now as well. Is there any chance of you making an answer (assuming you have suggestions for the other things as well)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second part can be proved rigorously.

1. If $y_0>0$, then the solution is bounded. Indeed, we have $y'>0$ when $y>0$, which implies that $y$ is an increasing function that stays positive at all times. In the opposite direction, $y'\le \frac{1}{3y_0+x^2}+\frac{2}{4+x^2}$, and since the integral of RHS converges, $y$ stays bounded. More precisely, 
   $$y(x)-y_0\le \int_0^\infty \frac{dx}{3y_0+x^2}+\int_0^\infty \frac{2\,dx}{4+x^2}$$
   which you can integrate to get an upper bound on $\lim_{x\to\infty} y(x)$.  I'm not very happy that this upper bound becomes huge when $y_0$ is close to $0$. But this defect can be fixed if we recall that the solution lines do not cross. Therefore, a solution with $y_0<1$ will always stay below the solution with $y_0=1$, and therefore will obey the upper bound for $y_0=1$.
2. If $y_0<0$, we want to prove that the solution stays below the parabola $y=-x^2/3$. One way to do this is to consider the function $u=y+x^2/3$ which satisfies the equation 
   $$u'=\frac{1}{3u}+\frac{2}{4+x^2}+\frac{2x}{3}$$
   On any interval $[0,M]$ the RHS is bounded above by $\frac{1}{3u}+B$ where $B$ is a constant that is greater than the sum of two other terms. Let's also make $B$ large enough so that $u(0)<-1/(3B)$. It follows that $u<-1/(3B)$ on the entire interval $[0,M]$, because $u$ cannot go up in the territory where the direction field has negative slope.

The above sounds informal, but can be made rigorous with an appropriate *comparison theorem* for ODE: e.g., if two functions $u_1,u_2$ have the same initial value at $x=0$ and satisfy $u_1'=f(u_1,x)$ and $u_2'\ge f(u_2,x)$, then $u_2(x)\ge u_1(x)$ for all $x\ge 0$. Here $u_1$ is a solution of ODE while $u_2$ could be called its *supersolution* (it outperforms the target rate of increase). The concept of *subsolution* is defined similarly. Sadly, they are not normally found in ODE textbooks which focus on solving equations precisely.

Speaking of being precise, I have no idea about the precise value of $y(\infty)$ for the initial value $y_0=1$.

Comment: Thanks, I think this is just what I wanted. I will take a good look at it.